Authorized user is deleted after the page is reloaded
Good afternoon everyone. I'm using discord oauth2, after successful login the user appears. But after reloading the page it is deleted.
Logs:
NOTICE: PHP message: [info] Matched route "auth_discord_login".
 NOTICE: PHP message: [debug] Checking for authenticator support.
NOTICE: PHP message: [debug] Checking support on authenticator.
NOTICE: PHP message: [debug] Checking support on authenticator.
NOTICE: PHP message: [debug] Remember-me cookie detected.
NOTICE: PHP message: [debug] Read existing security token from the session.
...
NOTICE: PHP message: [warning] Username could not be found in the selected user provider.
NOTICE: PHP message: [debug] Token was deauthenticated after trying to refresh it.
NOTICE: PHP message: [debug] Authenticator does not support the request.
NOTICE: PHP message: [debug] Clearing remember-me cookie.
NOTICE: PHP message: [info] Authenticator failed.
NOTICE: PHP message: [debug] Clearing remember-me cookie.

My security config:
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        users:
            entity:
                class: 'App\User\Domain\User'
                property: 'username'
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                always_remember_me: true
                lifetime: 2592000 # 1 month in seconds
                path: / # cookie path
                signature_properties: ['username']
                token_provider:
                    doctrine: true
            lazy: true
            provider: users
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\User\Application\Oauth2\DiscordAuthenticatorService
            logout:
                path: auth_discord_app_logout
                target: app_index

And auth service and controller code:
https://gist.github.com/LevPrav999/c2abad5f0d62d9cb8a160a40eb55b0a6
Debug bar:
Before refresh:
user id is shown
After refresh:
N/A is shown
My User.php class:

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BotRepositoryInterface::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'users')]
#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
class User implements UserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private ?string $username;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 250)]
    #[AssertConstraints\NotBlank]
    private ?string $description = "";

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
    #[AssertConstraints\NotBlank]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @param string|null $discordId
     */
    public function __construct(?string $discordId)
    {
        $this->username = $discordId;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(?int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(?string $discordId): void
    {
        $this->username = $discordId;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): void
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }


    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }

    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize(): string
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->description,
            $this->roles
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize(string $serialized): void
    {
        list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->description,
        $this->roles
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }


}

What i need to do to fix this error?
I tried changing the User class by adding serialization
